# I need to display my data from database to listview. I'm using arrayadapter with listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This is my method to get the data.Here its showing "change the type result to string".

```
public List<String> getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] coloumn = new String[]{KEY,NAME,DETAIL};
        Cursor c=ourDB.query(TABLE_NAME, coloumn, null, null, null, null, null);
        List<String> result =" ";
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        int iRow =c.getColumnIndex(KEY);
        int iName =c.getColumnIndex(NAME);
        int iDetails =c.getColumnIndex(DETAIL);
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
         result = result + c.getString(iRow)+" "+ c.getString(iName)+" = "+ c.getString(iDetails)+"\n";
             }

        return result;
    }
```

This is my class to view the data.

```
 public class View extends Activity {

        SimpleCursorAdapter adaptr;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.display);
            ListView lv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            Remind info = new Remind(this);
            info.open();
            List<String> data =info.getData();
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));

        }

 }
```

please any one can suggest any ideas. thanks..!

Comment: Whats the real question here?

Comment: The error show clearly _change the type result to string_ then you need to change it.

Comment: I have changed that. but then the return result is showing the error. thanks

Comment: What error does it show??

Comment: " change type of result to List<String>" and change method return type to String

Comment: You need to add your data to  results arraylist **results.add(result);** and add _returns results;_

Answer (score 0):

From the error that you have mentioned, this is an obvious problem.

The following line in getData() is assigning a string literal to a List.

```
List<String> result =" ";
```

Change that to

```
String result = " ";
```

Comment: i have changed sir. But then the return statement result is showing error.

Comment: You need to add the result string to the results and return the results.  results.add(result); return results;

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public List<String> getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] coloumn = new String[]{KEY,NAME,DETAIL};
    Cursor c=ourDB.query(TABLE_NAME, coloumn, null, null, null, null, null);
    List<String> result =" ";
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    int iRow =c.getColumnIndex(KEY);
    int iName =c.getColumnIndex(NAME);
    int iDetails =c.getColumnIndex(DETAIL);
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
     result = result + c.getString(iRow)+" "+ c.getString(iName)+" = "+ c.getString(iDetails)+"\n";
    results.add(result);             
}

    return results;
}
```

Comment: thank u for your help sir.. now my errors are gone .i have done some changes.

Comment: Now my app closed unexpectedly.

Comment: i have added my main activity and log cat above.

Comment: i think intent have some problems

Comment: mention line 68  at AddActivity.java

Comment: Intent i =new Intent("android.intent.action.View");
here you should pass uri for it like this.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contactUri);

Answer (score 0):

Directly add your database data to List :

```
results.add(" "+ c.getString(iRow)+" "+ c.getString(iName)+" = "+ c.getString(iDetails)+"\n");
```

Return String List instead String :

```
return results;
```

Remove this code which is no longer required :

List result =" ";